# socket.io-client breaks when running grunt build

Tags: socket.io, requirejs, gruntjs, yeoman

I have a Yeoman [`webapp`](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp) project, where I've added [`socket.io-client`](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client) using `bower`.

Everything works fine when I run the webapp with `grunt server`. But when I build it with `grunt build`, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined
```

By enabling source maps in `Gruntfile.js` (`generateSourceMaps: true`), I managed to track down the source of the error in **`socket.io.js`**:

```
/**
 * Add the transport to your public io.transports array.
 *
 * @api private
 */

io.transports.push('websocket');
```

What could make `io.transports` become *undefined* after running `grunt build`?

**UPDATE:**

Probably worth telling that I use RequireJS and it's configured like this:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: '../bower_components/jquery/jquery',
        // ...
        // socket.io: Try the node server first
        'socket.io': ['/socket.io/socket.io', '../bower_components/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io'],
    },
    shim: {
        // Export io object: https://gist.github.com/guerrerocarlos/3651490
        'socket.io': {
            exports: 'io'
        }
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'socket.io'], function ($, io) {
    'use strict';
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only have the socket.io-client defined in the paths:

```
paths: {
    'jquery': '../bower_components/jquery/jquery',
    'socket.io': '../bower_components/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io'
},
```

Also you should not set the io parameter (it is set globally) (or use something else like sio)

```
require(['jquery', 'socket.io'], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    // ...
});
```